# C# regex to remove BBCode color from string

Tags: c#, regex

```
string s = "I am an example of [color red]being colored[/color] at [color blue] any time[/color]";
```

How can I detect all the [color x] and [/color] words and delete them all?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(text, @"\[/?color\b.*?\]", string.Empty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas Trzesniewski's solution works:

Regex.Replace(text, @"[/?color\b.*?]", string.Empty)

Comment: If the BBtags cannot contain `[` and `]` inside, my solution is more robust.

Comment: If a BBCode can contain `[` but cannot contain `]`, rather than `\[/?color\b.*?\]`, you should use `\[/?color\b[^]]*]`. A `[^]]` negated character class can match any character other than `]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the text with the below regex:

```
\[/?color\b[^][]*]
```

The regex matches:

- `\[/?` - a literal `[` and an optional `/` after it (`?` means *1 or 0 repetitions*)
- `color\b` - a whole word `color` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `[^][]*` - 0 or more characters other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a literal `]`

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/D1bzG0)

```
string s = "I am an example of [color red]being colored[/color] at [color blue] any time[/color]";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"\[/?color\b[^][]*]", string.Empty));
```

Comment: If a BBCode can contain `[` but cannot contain `]`, rather than `\[/?color\b.*?\]`, you should use `\[/?color\b[^]]*]`. A `[^]]` negated character class can match any character other than `]`.